# Insert SQL to LINQ data into input form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can I insert data into this form field.
So I have my fancy looking form, and I want to add two values that I queried from the database into this.

HTML view:

```
@model CWebPortal.Models.onboard_test
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "OnBoarding", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <form>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="input-group input-group-icon1">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Project Name" name="projectname" value = "" required />
  <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-user" style="padding-top:20px;"></i> Project Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-group-icon1">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Developer" name="developer" />
  <div class="input-icon"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-top:20px"></i> Developer</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>

}
```

Controller with LINQ:

```
        var DataContext = new BalanceDataContext();
        var custQuery2 = (from m in DataContext.onboard_tests
                           orderby m.date_created descending
                           select m).Take(1);
        return View(custQuery2);
```

Model:

```
public class Onboard
{
    [Key]
    public Guid projectID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Developer { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
}
```

I want to just be like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Project Name" name="projectname" value = "@model.projectname" required />
```

Since I am not doing this the @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.projectname) method.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Your query returns a collection, not a single `onboard_tests` (use `.FirstOrDefault()`. And generate your html correctly using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectName)` etc. And remove your manual `<form>` tags - nested forms are invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.Take(1)` you should use `FirstOrDefault()`.

Explanation: your view has model of type `CWebPortal.Models.onboard_test`. But LINQ operator [`Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns a query of `IQueryable<CWebPortal.Models.onboard_test>` type no matter if you'll specify 10 entities or 1 entity. In order to get single entity (as your view expects) you should *execute* query and get single entity. Best way to do that is [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896(v=vs.110).aspx) method.